# Declaration of namespaces in PHP (5.3.5)

Tags: php, namespaces, include

Ok, I'm new to namespaces, here's the scenario... I have 2 files

libs/class.mysql.inc.php

```
class MySQL{

}
```

classes/class.mysql.inc.php

```
require_once('libs/class.mysql.inc.php'); 
interface MySQLTemplate{
}
class MySQLWrapper extends MySQL implements MySQLTemplate{
}
```

ok, so here's my question. How would I be able rename MySQLWrapper to MySQL? Obviously 'class MySQL extends MySQL' can't happen. I can't seem to declare a namespace before requiring the file either. (Well I can, but it doesn't accept the namespace). I don't want to touch the libs/class.mysql.inc.php file either (if poss).

Any hints? Tips? Possibilities here?

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you need to refer to `MySQLWrapper`, require such class with [`use`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) keyword:

```
use MySQLWrapper as MySQL;

//do your stuff with MySQL as an alias
```

Comment: I like, as I don't have to faff with Namespaces, but I still need to change every file where this is declared... I guess I've got to make a choice between adding 'App\' in: $db = new App\MySQL(); or 'use MySQLWrapper as MySQL;' above $db = new MySQL();

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it appears you can only define namespaces within files, any includes are ignored. I got round it by declaring a random namespace at the top of the file (PHP likes this to be before anything else). Then because the file is included the namespace of the inlcude class is global. So I got it working by:

libs/class.mysql.inc.php

```
class MySQL{

}
```

classes/class.mysql.inc.php

```
namespace Libs;
require_once('libs/class.mysql.inc.php'); 
namespace App;
interface MySQLTemplate{
}
class MySQL extends \MySQL implements MySQLTemplate{
}
```

Hope this helps someone else... I was scratching my head for a while because I didn't understand its behavoir.

Comment: This still insn't quite right... any future references of MySQL class are from the parent class. Doh!